# React+Webpack css error

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Error appears while build app with webpack. Can someone help me with that?

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> * {
|     color:red;
| }
```

webpack.config

```
module: {
    rules: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
    }, { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        use: [
            'style-loader', 
            'css-loader'
        ] 
    }]
},
```

Comment: It will be hard to help you without seeing your Webpack configuratoin.

Comment: added webpack config

Comment: What's the name of the file that contains your `* { color:red; }` code?

Comment: import './styles/styles.css';

Comment: Have you tried writing `use: [{ loader: "style-loader" }, { loader: "css-loader" }]` instead?

Comment: yes. Same error

Comment: That's frustrating. What version of Webpack are you using?

Comment: `"webpack": "^4.15.1",`

Comment: solve it with restart my laptop. Thx anyway